# order_by in block each rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-order-by, each

I have a loop for with order_by for :created_at and :desc

```
<% for comment in post.comments.order_by([:created_at, :desc]) %>
<% end %>
```

How can I doing the order_by([:created_at, :desc]) in block with each, e.j:

```
<% post.comments.each do |comment|%>
<% end %>
```

**Edited**

The code that working fine for me its:

```
post.comments.order([:created_at, :desc])[0,5].each do |comment|
```

with the [0,5] limit the result to interval.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

order method is what you're looking for:

```
<% post.comments.order("created_at desc").each do |comment|%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For me working fine this: `post.comments.order([:created_at, :desc])[0,5].each do |comment|`